# Catching an exception when terminating a program in JAVA

Tags: java, exception

Is there a way to do this?

I'm coding a program that has to iterate for a very long time, and while doing so it is supposed to write to file. I want to close the stream as soon as I terminate the program manually and by doing so, avoid the risk of loosing data because of the unclosed stream. There should be a way of doing this with exception handling, but I'm not sure. Any kind of suggestion is very appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Use a try-finally clause where the streams are closed in the `finally` block.  Or, if you're using Java 7, use the [try-with-resources block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way! I lost so much time with this, without noticing that streams are automatically closed when the program terminates...

Data hadn't been written because I wasn't using the flush() method after the write() method, like this:

```
out.write(line);
out.flush();
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: this is not an answer to your question! close the file, when you dont need it anymore. out.close()

Answer (score 2):

in main:

```
try {
   startapp();
} finally {
   closeAll();
}
```

in closeAll() you do what you do for a safe shutdown
The code in the finally block will executed even when exceptions will ocure.

Comment: It didn't work... But I found a way out, I will post it in a few seconds

Comment: this works! only if you call System.exit() what you never shoul do, it will not work. or when the vm crashes with internal error

Answer (score 1):

Using exceptions to control program execution the way you are describing is poor design. It's would be much better to use a shutdown hook.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // Close streams here
    }
});
```

This will handle most normal shutdowns just fine, though in the case of a hard halt (SIGKILL) the shutdown hooks are not guaranteed to be run. But that is no worse than if you were attempting to close the stream via a finally block.

Comment: I tried to test this, but I wasn't able to compile... Still, I already found the problem.

Comment: The code above does compile and work for me. What problems did you run into?